# PVC going empty after pod initialisation time GCP lost+found storage issue

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

Whatever mount path i add for PVC it is creating lost+found folder and deleting all other content.

I am trying to setup deployment with PVC

```
FROM python:3.5 AS python-build
ADD . /test
WORKDIR /test
CMD [ "python3", "./run.py" ]


apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-core
  labels:
    app: test-core
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-core
      tier: frontend
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-core
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: <My image>
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
          runAsUser: 1000
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: .05
          limits:
            memory: "256Mi"
            cpu: .10
        name: test-core
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9595
          name: http
        - containerPort: 443
          name: https
        readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 9595
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 3
            timeoutSeconds: 3
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 4
        envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: test-secret
        - configMapRef:
            name: test-new-configmap
        volumeMounts:
        - name: core-data
          mountPath: /test
        imagePullPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: core-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: core-claim
```

When i apply this file from kubernetes it's giving an error in the log cannot find file run.py that mean PVC going empty.

Whatever mount path a add it is creating lsot+found folder and deleting all other content.

Thanks

Comment: I think the `WORKDIR` instruction in your Dockerfile should be `/path` instead of `/test`

Comment: actully just for here i used it but it's same in actual scenario

Comment: @NicolasPepinster I have updated docker file and yaml file please check.i have removed init container also this is the file i am trying

Comment: @NicolasPepinster is there anything like i have to use initcontainer and prepopulate data ?

Comment: As you don't copy `run.py` in your Dockerfile, I suppose it's present in the PV  referred in the PVC ? Otherwise, why you don't copy it in your Dockerfile ?

Comment: There is issue of lost+found on volume side

Comment: @NicolasPepinster any idea lost+found automatically create and data delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your `Dockerfile`, when you run `docker build -t <imagename> .`, it will copy all files on your current directory to container image. And when you start this container, it will look for `run.py`.

If one of theese files is `run.py`, which actually should be, then your deployment yaml file is not correct, because you mount another PV to that directory, which will overwrite your files which you copied before and it won't able to find `run.py`

Hope it helps.

Comment: How to get that all file inside pv if i am mounting another pv to that directory?

Comment: you can create one pod, mount it this pvc to this pod, then with command `kubectl cp` you can copy your files to target mounted pv, then delete pod, and mount this pv again to your this deployment

Comment: i think it's an issue of lost+found which if simple use mountpath as `/var/` it's adding lost+found folder and delete all the data inside var

Comment: So each and every time i have to use initcontainer ? what if pod dies data will be there ?

Comment: Persistent Volume, is used for persistent data, it means, when pod dies, your data won't lost. You can mount it again for new pods.

Comment: Okay so i have to write initcontainer ? which will copy data from docker file to  PV and again attach pv that to pod.?

Comment: `initContainers:
      - name: set-dir-owner
        image: busybox:1.29.2
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        command: ['sh', '-c' ,'cp -r /test /test']
        volumeMounts:
        - name: core-data
          mountPath: /test`

Comment: When you build your Docker image, put your `run.py` to same folder with `Dockerfile`, and `ADD . /test` command will copy it for you to container image, then you don't have to mount anything, it will be in your image. No initContainer, and no PV is needed

Comment: i am doing same command in docker 'ADD . /test' so it will copy all data to test folder and my mount path for volume is `/test` so data should be persisted instead of that folder going empty.

Comment: please read answer on this post to understand basic mount behavior https://superuser.com/questions/200685/what-does-linux-do-with-existing-files-in-a-mount-point

Comment: Thankyou so much fro sharing answer got the idea about mount path